# Faking a login w/Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm creating a fake login experience in a pre-existing prototype. I think my problem is that there's already a click event on the button that advances it to the next div (it's a single page setup with divs that slide in) and I need to add the below validation functionality to the same button. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#login_button').click(function(e){
  var username_input = $('input[placeholder*="Hint"]'), 
      password_input = $('input[placeholder*="Password"]'),
      username = $(username_input).val(),
      password = $(password_input).val(),
      login_errors = 0;

  if ((username == '') || (password == '')) {
    console.log("Please enter your username and password.");
    login_errors = 1;
  } else  if ((username == 'my_username') && (password == 'my_password')) {
    console.log("Username and password are correct.");  
  } else {
    console.log("Your username or password are incorrect. Retry.");
    login_errors = 1;
  }

  if (login_errors != 0){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I'm getting a little lost there at the end. I can get the button to validate the input and to advance to the next page, but I don't know how to get it to do both of these things at the same time.

Comment: Just set window.location

Comment: It seems to be a single page (with divs that slide in)

Comment: Thanks - it's animating in another div, though. Not changing which file is open. Maybe I'm missing some other aspect of window.location that you're referring to?

Comment: When you say "but I don't know how to get it to do both of these things at the same time" it's not clear to me what you are asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, @JackZelig is correct.

Comment: Sure - As the prototype exists already, there's a login page where you click "Log in" but there's no username and password required. When you click the button, the current div slides out to the left and the next div slides in from the right. My problem is that I'm trying to get that same log in button to also verify the input. I've managed to do those two things separately but not together.

Comment: `username_input = $('input[placeholder*="Hint"]'),` this looks a bit dodgy to me. Why would you be getting the username from an input with a placeholder of "hint"? Apart from that, could you post a link or a JSfiddle where we could see this not working, as the code you have provided so far is not really enough to go on. **Update** Just tried your code out and it works as expected for me. Must be another factor involved.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit dodgy...it's a monster prototype with multiple funnels that all have this one thing in common (and it's a convoluted code base). The hint thing has to do specifically with my company. I've edited it in the fiddle....and I just put the fiddle up. I might have just answered my own question. Sorry - I'm not completely clear on how to make this work. I do appreciate your help though. @JackZelig

Comment: It took me a few minutes, but here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kapunahele/0c9htr4o/

Comment: It works as expected for me :)

Comment: @JackZelig - doing a fiddle really helped me out - thanks for the suggestion. The fiddle worked easily, but in the project, the button has lots of js going on already and is using a class that is applied to all buttons through out the prototype. I think I just have to add an ID and refactor what's already in there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

In my project, I had to refactor to sort out some logic. I made a fiddle that worked right away and helped clarify things for me:

jsfiddle.net/kapunahele/0c9htr4o